# Как изменить значения top и bottom через jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

При клике на кнопку, меню, через jquery, задаётся `top: 0`.
А при клике на другую кнопку задаём `bottom: -menuHeight`.
Не спрашивайте меня Зачем!??.

При нажатии на кнопки меню должно менять своё позиционирование.

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос-то? Как выключить `top: 0px`?

Comment: Да именно так, а после удалить bottom: -menuHeight. и так каждый раз

Comment: А не легче `css` класс менять? `addClass()`, `removeClass()` Просто в одном классе `top` прописан, а в другом - нет.

Comment: Не тот случай. высота меню изменяется динамически.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `removeProp()`.

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $('#menu').removeProp('bottom').css('top', '0px');
});
$('#btn2').on('click', function() {
    $('#menu').removeProp('top').css('bottom', '[-menuHeight]px');
});
```

Comment: initial не поддерживается ie, к сожалению.

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуйте новый вариант

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, но ответ оказался куда долее прост.  ('.menu').css({ top: ''  })

Comment: Ваш ответ тоже работает. Ещё раз спасибо. Хотя нет. Не работает Ваш вариант.